Error using a VHDL function inside package into a systemverilog module. Mixed VHDL - SystemVerilog -mixedsvvh example
I present the VHDL & SystemVerilog code, of a very simple example.
I would like to know if it's possible to do what I am trying. And in case it is, why I am getting an error Considered I am using Questasim this is the code:
my_package.vhd
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package my_package is
    -- Type declarations
    type my_array is array (0 to 3) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    -- Constant declarations
    constant MY_CONSTANT : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "10101010";

    -- Function declarations
    function add(a, b: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector;
end package my_package;

package body my_package is
    function add(a, b: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
    variable result : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    begin
        result := std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b));
        return result;
    end function;
end package body my_package;

sv_module.sv
    // Import VHDL package and its contents
    import my_package::*;
    

module sv_module;
    
    
    logic [7:0] a, b, result;

    initial begin
        a = 8'h05;
        b = 8'h03;
        result = add(a, b);
        $display("Result of VHDL add: %h", result);
    end
endmodule

I tried to compile both of them by:
`vcom -mixedsvvh -work ../my_lib ../vhd_source/my_package.vhd
vlog -mixedsvvh -work ../my_lib ../sv_source/sv_module.sv`
Is it possible what I am trying to do? I would like to know why compiling sv_module.sv, is only possible if I use as destination library the same folder as for my_package.vhd, ../my_lib. Otherwise I get the error: vlog-13006 Could not find the package
And also I would like to know why, afterwards when trying to simulate, I get the error : Error (suppressible): ../sv_source/sv_module.sv(13): (vopt-7063) Failed to find 'add' in hierarchical name 'add'.
Regards.

In addition to the comment above, cross language support can vary between tools. Hence it is usually best to keep cross language elements to a minimum, particularly if you want to support multiple tools.

It is not currently possible to procedurally call a procedure defined in one HDL language directly from another HDL language. Questa's -mixedsvvh switch is for sharing type information when connecting ports at mixed HDL port boundaries.

And there is any explanation to the compilation of sv_module.sv always fails, unless I pick the same library where the package was also compiled?

You search other libraries with the -L option
